# What is it called when someone does an action they don't fully understand?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

For example, someone speaking and writing the English language, but not actually knowing how to use it properly.

Comment: I think it's called "programming".

Comment: Hey, bob! Welcome to ELU. You need to give us more to work with if you want any good answers. Also you should include any of the research you've done trying to solve this question on your own and insert all that I've just mentioned into an edited version of your OP. Also click on "HELP" above you to the right and take the "tour" when you get a minute. You'll be glad you did. Good luck, and we'll see you around. :-)

Comment: It's called "learning by doing".

Comment: You know, Blessed Geek is onto something. I could call a *person* who is doing something without having a sound foundation or knowledge, a *learner*. Do you have another example to include? What exactly prompted you to search for this term? (I'm trying to find a way for you to keep the question open.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if a person is using the English language but is not totally confident then you could say that person is just `attempting`. Is there really a specific name for it though, I don't think there is mate.

Tell me if I'm wrong though, I'd like to know myself.

Comment: No, I think you're right. I can't think of anything either.. Thanks though!

Comment: Hey, Blake M! Welcome to ELU. Your answers need to be supported by linked citation to some authority. Also click on "HELP" above you to the right and take the "tour" when you get a minute. You'll be glad you did. Good luck, and we'll see you around. Sorry for the "boilerplate" greeting. :-)

Comment: @LittleEva I will included citation when necessary, in this answer, it is not necessary.

Comment: Do what you wish, just trying to help-out.

Answer (score 1):

Verb to *blunder:*

> To move, act, or perform, blindly or stupidly. [OED]

Answer (score 0):

I think [*cargo-culting*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Cargo-Culting) might be an appropriate phrase. I see it used often in the programming world but the concept is applicable anywhere.

Here's the history of the phrase: [Cargo cult](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult)

> **Metaphorical uses of the term**
>
> The term "cargo cult" has been used metaphorically to describe an
>   attempt to recreate successful outcomes by replicating circumstances
>   associated with those outcomes, although those circumstances are
>   either unrelated to the causes of outcomes or insufficient to produce
>   them by themselves. In the former case, this is an instance of the
>   post hoc ergo propter hoc fallacy.
>
> The metaphorical use of "cargo cult" was popularized by physicist
>   Richard Feynman at a 1974 Caltech commencement speech, which later
>   became a chapter in his book *Surely You're Joking, Mr. Feynman!*, where
>   he coined the phrase "cargo cult science" to describe activity that
>   had some of the trappings of real science (such as publication in
>   scientific journals) but lacked a basis in honest experimentation.

Comment: Hey, Jonah. How does the concept of "cargo-culting" relate to  "not actually knowing how to use [the English language] properly"?

Comment: In cargo-culting, people were ritually imitating the behaviors of Americans (eg, building non-functional replicas of planes) without actually understanding how what they were imitating worked: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cargo+cult.  So, eg, a foreigner non-sensically stringing together overheard English words seems similar.

Comment: OK, just checking.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like learning something "by rote." From [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/by+rote):

> *by rote*:
>
> [of learning or memorizing] done as habit and without thinking.